# Negative word matching

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm about to go crazy with this. I am trying to match all strings that end with `.html`, but not those ending in `/index.html`. For rewrite purposes, you will have guessed. (I'm using nginx)

I have tried things like:

```
^(.*[^(\/index)])\.html$

^(.*)(?!index)\.html$
```

But the dot always seems to eat up the whole thing.

```
# Should match
/page.html
/folder/page.html

# Should not match
/page
/page/index.html
/index.html
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state yours, but many regex flavors support lookbehinds. Which in your case could be used as:

```
(?<!index)\.html$
```

Comment: I think I can. Phew, I think it works adding `(.*)` before to capture the match

Answer (score 0):

One fairly simple way that is guaranteed to work:

```
.*([^i].*|i[^n].*|in[^d].*|ind[^e].*|inde[^x].*|index.+)\.html
```

This will match everything `.*\.html` will match, unless it ends with index.html.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
^([^(\/index)]*)\.html$
```

Actually, I think that will not match `/index/page.html`.

Comment: `[^index]` matches a single character which is not `i`, `n`, `d`, etc.